# Can I use either commands in MySQL? INDEX and FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

So I am assigning foreign key and wanted to know which is better to use index or foreign key

This one:

```
CREATE TABLE meeting (
    meeting_id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    room_id INT(11),
    name TINYTEXT,
    date DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY(room_id) REFERENCES room(room_id)
);
```

Or this one:

```
CREATE TABLE meeting (
    meeting_id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    room_id INT(11),
    name TINYTEXR,
    date DATE,
    INDEX(room_id)
);
```

Comment: A foreign key will require an index (it will usually make one if there isn't one present). So, the first incorporates the second, but has a lot extra going for it. As you specify you want a foreign key, I would assume you want that extra functionality, so go for the first. If you don't need or want this, go for the second one.

Answer (score 2):

`index` and `foreign key` are two different things.

A `foreign key` means a `meeting` can't have a `room_id` value that doesn't appear in `room`'s `room_id` column.
An `index` means that you can query `meetings` by `room_id` much more efficiently, without having to scan the entire table.

If both `meeting` and `room` are fairly large, and you have several queries combining them (either by joins or subqueries), I'd have both the `index` and the `foreign key`.

Comment: snap :) is it amazing or worrying how close two answers to the same question could be?

Answer (score 1):

Foreign Keys and Indexes are very different things.

You add the foreign key to enforce integrity of your data. You're saying, room_id is only ever allowed to be a number from room.room_id. It's a great property to have and you should always try to use them where possible.

You add the index to tell the database how you're going to be searching for data so that it can prepare the necessary datastructures to do that efficiently. In this case, once you add the index queries searching for meetings in specific rooms will be fast.

The two concepts are really totally unrelated.